# JQUERY submit form and display result - multiple forms on page

Tags: php, jquery, forms

Im new to Jquery and trying to recreate something muddled together a while ago, with a similar function.

i have pasted my code here: http://pastebin.com/SYM45WPw

I have a table which is created base on results of a form on the previous page (this is all working ok) with Student names in the first column, then every column after that has will be a result for testing requirement, simply a drop down with Pass / Fail, and for each person and each requirement i want to go along and pick the result, and submit the results to DB in thhe back ground and then removed the Select option and displays the result.

Currently on the post_result.php i have this, just to text i am getting a result:

```
if($_POST['studentID'] != ""){
echo "Success";
}
```

All help is much appreciated,

**Edit:** (taken from pastebin link)

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
$student_name = $_POST['student_name'];
$class = $_POST['class'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("select#result").change(function() {

    var studentID = $(this).find("input[name='student_name']").val();

        var result = $(this).serialize();

        $.post('post_result.php', result, function(data) {

                // We not pop the output inside the #output DIV.
                $("#output-" + studentID).html(data);

        });
$("#"+studentID+"-formarea").hide();
    return false;
});

});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>

<?php


    require 'db_connect.php';

    $header=1;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM  requirements WHERE   `class` = '$class' && month = $month ") or die("Error:". mysql_errno());

?>
<table class="tg" border="1">
  <tr>
      <th class="tg-031e">Student Name</th>
    <?php  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<th class="tg-031e">'.$row['requirement'].'</th>';
        $header++;
    }
        ?>
  </tr>
  <?php 
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($student_name); $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo ' <td class="tg-031e">'.$student_name[$i].'</td>';
        for ($count = 1; $count < $header; $count++) {
            echo '<td><div id="'.$student_name.'-formarea">'
                    . '<form method="POST" id="form-'.$student_name.'">'
                    . '<input type="hidden" name="student_name" value="'.$student_name.'" />'
                    . '<select name="result" id="result"><option selected>Select Result</option>'
                    . '<option value="Pass">Pass</option><option value="Fail">Fail</option></select>'
                    . '</form></div>'
                    . '<div id="output-'.$student_name[$i].'"></div></td>';
        }
    echo'</tr>';
  }
  ?>

</table>


    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're serializing a Select element, not the form, and you must serialize the form.
For example:

```
<form id="myForm" action="blabla" method="blabla">
    <select id="result" name="result">
    <option>Bla Bla Bla</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="student_name" />
    <!-- ...more elements .... -->
</form>
```

So you have to replace:

```
var result = $(this).serialize()
//by:
var result = $("#myForm").serialize()
```

Comment: THanks for the quick reply - I have changed that but it still doesn't work - nothing Is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In the file you are sending data to via Ajax you have 'studentID' as your key but in the form you are serializing, the keys are assigned from the name='' attribute. That would make your keys: 'student_name' and 'result'.

```
if($_POST['studentID'] != ""){
    echo "Success";
}
```

One way you could make sure of this is by placing the following into the php file your Ajax is sending and receiving. This will print an array of the post content being received by your php file.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

The results form that array will show up in the div where you are telling Ajax to place the results.

This is a good way to serialize the form you are working on for Ajax.

```
 var result = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have done so but still nothing - if i open the element inspector and select something from the dropdown i can see it request post_result.php but there is no reply?